# swift skips first variable update

Tags: swift, cs193p

I've been doing the Standford CS193p free course online and I have a strange situation with assignment 6. I'm supposed to create a theme list from which the user can directly start a game with the chosen theme. This list can be edited and when in editMode a tap gesture is used to open a sheet from which the tapped theme is edited. For this the tap gesture takes the index of the tapped theme and stores it as chosenThemeIndex.

I don't understand why this doesn't work the first time after running the code, meaning tapping on any list item opens always index 0 the first time, regardless of tapping on an item with another index. Then when closing the editing sheet and tapping on any other list item the correct theme is opened for editing. This means for me that Swift is skipping the first update from 0 to another index on chosenThemeIndex. Why is this happening and how can I correct this?

The complete app code can be pulled from branch **Assignment6** on: https://github.com/kranca/Memorize.git

```
import SwiftUI

struct ThemeChooser: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: ThemeStore

    @State private var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
    @State private var editing = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(store.themes) { theme in
                    let game = store.themes[theme].emojis.count > 1 ? EmojiMemoryGame(theme: theme) : nil
                    NavigationLink(destination: store.themes[theme].emojis.count > 1 ? EmojiMemoryGameView(game: game!) : nil, label: {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            HStack {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text(theme.name)
                                    Text("Pairs: \(theme.cardPairs)")
                                }
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                    .size(width: 30, height: 45)
                                    .fill()
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(rgbaColor: theme.rgbaColor))
                            }
                            Text(theme.emojis)
                        }
                        // call on gesture active only when in editMode
                        .gesture(editMode == .active ? tap(on: store.themes.firstIndex(of: theme) ?? 0) : nil)
                    })
                }
                .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                    store.themes.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                })
                .onMove(perform: { indexSet, newOffset in
                    store.themes.move(fromOffsets: indexSet, toOffset: newOffset)
                })
            }
            .navigationTitle("Choose a theme!")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) { editMode == .active ? newThemeButton : nil }
                ToolbarItem { EditButton() }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $editing) {
                ThemeEditor(theme: $store.themes[chosenThemeIndex])
            }
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
        }
    }

    // variable I want to update
    @State private var chosenThemeIndex: Int = 0

    // gesture which takes tapped index and updates chosenThemeIndex
    func tap(on tapedThemeIndex: Int) -> some Gesture {
        TapGesture().onEnded {
            chosenThemeIndex = tapedThemeIndex
            editing = true
        }
    }

    private var newThemeButton: some View {
        Button("Add New Theme") {
            chosenThemeIndex = 0
            store.insertTheme(named: "", cardPairs: 2)
            editing = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why even work with indices, why not use the selected object directly?

Comment: Your store should store elements (aka `Theme`) which conform to `Identifiable` -- especially when you implement create, update, delete methods. You may also introduce a getter for `ThemeStore` which returns a theme by its `id`.  This could be implemented with a _local_ extension, i.e. no need to change the API of the ThemeStore itself. As Joakim already pointed out, _indices_ can be error prone when you have a container where the number of elements change and will be modified. ;)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried that in the first place, but I get a similar error. If I declare chosenThemeIndex as Theme? and adapt the rest of the gesture and gesture call then on the first tap chosenThemeIndex isn't updated from nil to whatever Theme I choose. I can also initialize chosenThemeIndex with an empty Theme and I get a very similar behavior in which the empty Theme is opened first.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I also tried your approach, added a method func getTheme(with id: Int) -> Theme? and at the end I get the same result. On the first tap I get some other Theme (for example the one with id = 1) instead of the one I intended. Then after closing that one and open another one everything works just fine. Also Theme was already conforming to Identifiable. So my best guess is that there is something within the List which is causing this strange behavior.